# Is it possible to generate two secret strings in one CloudFormation SecretsManager secret?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I want to create a SecretsManager secret with two values both generated on the fly.  Is that possible and how do I do it?

For example, if I wanted the final secret to look like this in JSON, what would the CloudFormation yaml look like?

```
{
  "password": "<Generated Value>",
  "serviceId": "fd07f2ab-96bd-4c5c-a4a9-9b8c43b666d7",
  "login": "<Different Generated Value>"
}
```

If this is part of a CF template that generates the password part of the secret string, how would I generate a dynamic 'login' field as well?

```
#This is a Secret resource with a randomly generated password in its SecretString JSON.
MySecretA:
  Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'
  Properties:
    Name: MySecretForAppA
    Description: "This secret has a dynamically generated secret password and login."
    GenerateSecretString:
      SecretStringTemplate: '{"service-id": "<some guid>"}'
      GenerateStringKey: "password"
      PasswordLength: 30
      ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the `AWS::SecretsManager::Secret` resource only generates a single secret.

I could not find a way to refer to the actual contents of the secret via `!Ref`, which would have allowed two secrets to be generated, then referenced and combined in another resource. The only `!Ref` value available is the ARN of the secret.

Thus, I couldn't see a way to create two secrets in the one resource.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS::SecretsManager::Secret resource does not support generating multiple random keys in a single secret. One way to accomplish this today is to leverage a custom CloudFormation resource (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). You can write a custom resource lambda that generates two random strings and does a PutSecretValue on the secret with the new values.

Another possible option is to have CloudFormation generate two secrets (one for username and one for password). I would not recommend this approach since every time you need the secret you will need to do two retrieves and it doubles your AWS Secrets Manager costs.

Answer (score -1):

You could create **two** secrets, and only use one.

For example, you could create one for the *password*:

```
MySecretPassword:
  Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'
  Properties:
    Name: MySecretPasswordForAppA
    Description: "This secret has a dynamically generated secret password."
    GenerateSecretString:
      SecretStringTemplate: '{"serviceId": "<some guid>"}'
      GenerateStringKey: "password"
      PasswordLength: 30
      ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
```

And then another one that creates the `login` value, and uses the generated value guarded by `MySecretPassword`:

```
MySecret:
  Type: 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret'
  Properties:
    Name: MySecretForAppA
    Description: "This secret has a dynamically generated secret password and login."
    GenerateSecretString:
      SecretStringTemplate:
        !Join:
          - ''
          - '{ "password": "'
          - !Join:
            - ':'
            - '{{resolve'
            - 'secretsmanager'
            - !Ref: MySecretPassword
            - 'SecretString'
            - 'password}}'
          - '", "service-id": "'
          - !Join:
            - ':'
            - '{{resolve'
            - 'secretsmanager'
            - !Ref: MySecretPassword
            - 'SecretString'
            - 'serviceId}}'
          - '" }'
      GenerateStringKey: "login"
      PasswordLength: 30
      ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
```